# My wife telecommutes. Mortgage on my name but she is on the title. Can we tax deduct?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, tax-deduction

My wife telecommutes for her employer. We both are joint owners of the property but the mortgage is only on my name. Can we tax deduct the mortgage interest and insurance even though she isn't responsible for the mortgage (she is a co-owner)?

Comment: Are you looking for the home office deduction? https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/home-office-deduction

Comment: What are you trying to deduct?

Answer (score 3):

What filing status do you use? Are you married filing jointly? Then yes, mortgage interest is deductible on your joint return. Filing separately? Then the person paying the mortgage can deduct it. Or if you share that expense, you can share the deduction. This link has [good info from H&R Block](https://www.hrblock.com/tax-center/filing/adjustments-and-deductions/married-filing-separately-and-mortgage-interest/).